# how to set lable value with their % value in telerik Pie chart

Tags: asp.net, pie-chart, telerik-reporting

When I generate telerik Pie chart. I want to concatenate lable value with %data value but I am not getting both values.my code-

```
ChartSeries objChartSeries = new ChartSeries("Pie");
            objChartSeries.Type = ChartSeriesType.Pie;

            objChartSeries.Appearance.LegendDisplayMode = ChartSeriesLegendDisplayMode.ItemLabels;
            objChartSeries.Appearance.LabelAppearance.Visible = true;
            objChartSeries.Appearance.ShowLabelConnectors = true;
            objChartSeries.Appearance.ShowLabels = true;
            objChartSeries.Appearance.DiameterScale = 0.6;

            objChartSeries.DataLabelsColumn = Xtext + "#Y";
            //objChartSeries.DefaultLabelValue = "#Y";

            //RadChart1.Legend.TextBlock.Text = ddlX.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
            //RadChart1.Legend.Visible = true;

            RadChart1.Series.RemoveSeries();
            RadChart1.Series.Add(objChartSeriesBlank);
            RadChart1.Series.Add(objChartSeries);

            RadChart1.Series[1].DataYColumn = Yval;

            RadChart1.DataSource = dsResult;
            RadChart1.DataBind();
```

[image: Pie chart screen shot]
**I want my chart like E1007(40%)...**

Answer (score 1):

```
objChartSeries.DataLabelsColumn = SomeDecimal.ToString("P");
```